# Awkward-array test for elements of one JaggedArray in another

Tags: python, physics, awkward-array

I need to perform a calculation on a JaggedArray, but only if the elements in the JaggedArray are in contained in another JaggedArray. I'd like to receive back a mask with `True` if the element in is another JaggedArray, or `False` otherwise (ie. should be a `np.array`). I've been looking for a way to do this in awkward-array version 0 or 1. However, I haven't be able to find a direct way to do so. `in` doesn't appear to work, and I haven't found an equivalent for `np.isin(...)` (mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/issues/134), but seems to have been closed without a replacement). To be concrete, I'm looking for:

```py
import awkward as ak
import numpy as np

# Example arrays:
full_array = ak.fromiter([[1,2,3], [], [0,1,2,3,4,5]])
selected_array = ak.fromiter([[2], [], [7]])
# Desired output
desired_output = np.array([True, False, False])
```

For awkward0, I get:

```py
>>> selected_array in full_array
~/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awkward/array/base.py in __bool__(self)
    138
    139     def __bool__(self):
--> 140         raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()")
    141
    142     __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I also tried some other variations of things like `selected_array.pad(1).fillna(-10).flatten() in full_array` without success. I did find a workaround, but it seems rather indirect:

```py
workaround_array = full_array.ones_like() * selected_array.pad(1).fillna(-100).flatten()
assert (desired_output == (workaround_array == full_array).any()).all()
```

For awkward1, I get a result, but it appears to be wrong (or I'm not sure what it means).

```py
>>> import awkward1 as ak1
... ak1_full_array = ak1.from_awkward0(full_array)
... ak1_selected_array = ak1.from_awkward0(selected_array)
>>> ak1_selected_array in ak1_full_array
True
```

Is there a more direct way of testing for elements in a JaggedArray? Am I somehow misusing `in`? What about the case of more than one value per JaggedArray entry, where the workaround doesn't work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have what is maybe at least a more direct method, but I still don't think it is great. I'd also be interested in seeing other solutions.

```
output = ak.fromiter([np.isin(selected_array[index], full_array[index]) 
                      for index in range(len(selected_array))])
# This is a JaggedArray with entries [[True], [], [False]]
# output.any() will then match desired_output
```